# Excel custom axis label

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I'm having troubles with some charts I'm creating using Excel. Some of the values I'm plotting are too big (2<sup>64</sup>) to be labeled in the axis. Due to this, Excel automatically puts them in scientific notation. What I should do is to use "labels" for all the numeric values in the axis.

I'm wondering if there is a way to produce a chart without labeling the axis with the actual numbers and make the labels like a, b, c, d, etc., instead of the actual numbers, but using the numbers to plot the graph. Then I can show a chart below defining like this: a= XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, b = YYYYYYYYYYYYYY, etc...

Comment: Can you plot with a log scale?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create a "helper" column of data that can be used to place points that can be labeled, the using an Excel addin called XY Chart Labeler to assign the points custom values for the labels.  Generally, you'll need to:

1. Create two additional columns for the helper series (which will be
   XY data).  The X column values will all be 0 (or your minimum value,
   you want them to display over top of the axis). The Y column values
   are whatever you want the labels to be.
2. Add the additional series to the chart, make it's an XY (Scatter) type (if that's different then the main chart type.
3. Format the points so they're invisible (no marker type, line color, etc...).
4. Install [XY Chart Labeler](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm) (if you haven't already-it fills a critical gap in Excel's capabilities).
5. Add custom labels to your "helper" series, based upon the values you have in its columns.  You can even add an additional column beyond the "Y" Axis values.

Here's a sample of what can be done with this process:

[image: Log Labels]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to try to do that. I appreciate it.